# Why does Android DatagramSocket.receive() completes in 0 ms?

Tags: android, udp, broadcast

I am programming Android App that receives UDP broadcasts (sent from PC at 10Hz), I am measuring time before and after DataGramSocket.receive(). Usually it takes 100ms for receive( )to complete (as it's expected for 10Hz data), but quite often I get 0 ms difference in time before and after receive(). Does it means the packet has been dropped?

Answer (score 0):

It means the packet had already arrived before you called recv().

Comment: But isn't recv() blocking call? (I checked SO_TIMEOUT it's 0, so it unlimited). And shouldn't receive block and wait untill the second packet is received?